# how do I use a string returned as an ajax response to assign to a php variable

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I select an option from a drop down menu(id="field"), and on the basis of this value I wish to generate another drop down menu, I use ajax to retrieve the value of field1 input. the function is:

```
function showbranches(degree)
{
  var XMLHttp=false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     XMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
     XMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

  XMLHttp.open("POST","SORS/sendegree.php?degree="+degree,true);
  XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if (XMLHttp.readyState==4 && XMLHttp.status == 200)
  {
      document.getElementById('br').innerHTML=XMLHttp.responseText; 
  }  
 }
 XMLHttp.send(null); 
}
```

code in sendegree.php file is simply

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['degree'];
?>
```

Now I try to receive the string returned by ajax code into a php variable using statement:

```
<?php
  $state="<span id=\"br\"></span>"; 
  echo $state;
?>
```

Now the problem is, the first statement for echo works fine, but i am not able to use $state as a variable in sql query as below

```
$get_cty=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abc WHERE city='$state'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you can't do that. run the query from the file accessed via ajax instead

Comment: `$_REQUEST` has been deprecated for several years now because it is inherently unsafe. Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` instead. After fixing that, please fix your SQL queries before [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) drops your database (iow. use `mysqli` or `PDO` with parametrized queries instead of concatenating SQL injections together as you do now).

Answer (score -2):

You need to concatenate the variable

Try this

```
$get_cty=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abc WHERE city='".$state."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

How I learned it in college was whenever you needed a variable to a value in the query to you added `'".."'` after the equals sign then put the variable in the middle.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In PHP you can inline expand variables in strings enclosed with double quotes, so `"Hello $dear World"` is equivalent to `'Hello '.$dear.' World'`. And your code is as such equivalent to the topicstarter's code. Glad to hear though that your college didn't teach about SQL injection either.

Comment: you are correct sir, i m a starter, i m working n its own ( no college thing).

Comment: over the sql injection, the php variable that is being inserted into the sql query is from a drop down menu, will that still be a threat ? I will be glad to hear from you.. @Niels

Comment: @user2371258 user input is always a thread. Someone could easily replace the dropdown with an input field in their browser, or use other ways to manipulate the postback.

Comment: @Niels have you ever thought that he already accounted for that somewhere else in his code. He could have easily used an if statement to check to see if there was a selection made and if it was one of the selections he put there. So lay off the guy. Oh and if you look at his code he is encasing $state in single quotes in a double quote string so yes he does need to concatenate if he wants to keep that structure.